# Затруднение с наложением и закраской полигонов

Tags: c++

Есть задача: написать и отладить программу с использованием функциональных возможностей OpenGL для реализации отсечения фигур по полю вывода. Я использовал реализацию алгоритма Сазерленда-Ходжмена (Последовательное отсечение многоугольника (его координаты заданы в функции display). И у меня возникла ситуация не очень правильного результата в графическом виде (см. рисунок). Доля "синего" (вошедшего в рамки красного поля - поля вывода) цвета должна быть больше, но получается наложение..перекрытие. Именно в данном конкретном случае, при изменении значений многоугольника (уменьшении количества вершин и придании формы прямоугольника, все отрабатывает хорошо) (рис. с прямоугольником).

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне решить данную проблему? [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: Рис с прямоугольником]

```
#include <glut.h>

struct Point{
    float x,y;
} w[4],oVer[4]; 
int Nout;    

void drawPoly(Point p[],int n){
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);            
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        glVertex2f(p[i].x,p[i].y);    
    glEnd();
}

bool insideVer(Point p){    
        if((p.x>=w[0].x)&&(p.x<=w[2].x))        
            if((p.y>=w[0].y)&&(p.y<=w[2].y))
                return true;                
        return false;        
}

void addVer(Point p){        
    oVer[Nout]=p;        
    Nout=Nout+1;
}

Point getInterSect(Point s,Point p,int edge){
    Point in;            
    float m;
    if(w[edge].x==w[(edge+1)%4].x){ //Vertical Line        
        m=(p.y-s.y)/(p.x-s.x);    
        in.x=w[edge].x;                
        in.y=in.x*m+s.y;
    }
    else{//Horizontal Line            
        m=(p.y-s.y)/(p.x-s.x);    
        in.y=w[edge].y;
        in.x=(in.y-s.y)/m;        
    }    
    return in;
}

void clipAndDraw(Point inVer[],int Nin){
    Point s,p,interSec;    
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        Nout=0;
        s=inVer[Nin-1];
        for(int j=0;j<Nin;j++)
        {            
            p=inVer[j];
            if(insideVer(p)==true){                
                if(insideVer(s)==true){
                    addVer(p);                                    
                }
                else{
                    interSec=getInterSect(s,p,i);
                    addVer(interSec);                    
                    addVer(p);                    
                }
            }
            else{        
                if(insideVer(s)==true){
                    interSec=getInterSect(s,p,i);                
                    addVer(interSec);                                                    
                }
            }
            s=p;            
        }        
        inVer=oVer;        
        Nin=Nout;    
    }    
    drawPoly(oVer,4); 
}

void init(){
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);        
    glLoadIdentity();    
    glOrtho(0.0,100.0,0.0,100.0,0.0,100.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);    //поле
    w[0].x =20,w[0].y=10;
    w[1].x =20,w[1].y=80;
    w[2].x =80,w[2].y=80;
    w[3].x =80,w[3].y=10;
}
void display(void){    
    Point inVer[5];
    init();
    // As Window for Clipping //красный - поле
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);        
    drawPoly(w,4); 
    // As Rect - зеленый = объект наш
    glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    inVer[0].x =10,inVer[0].y=50;
    inVer[1].x =15,inVer[1].y=25;
    inVer[2].x =30,inVer[2].y=35;
    inVer[3].x =50,inVer[3].y=28;
    inVer[4].x =45,inVer[4].y=45;
      glFlush();

    drawPoly(inVer,5); 
    // As Rect - синий, то, что отсекается
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    clipAndDraw(inVer,5);        
    // Print
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(400,400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("Polygon Clipping!");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

введите сюда код
```

Comment: Так стоп, вы хотите отсекать с помощью OpenGL или что?

Comment: Да, так требуется, отсекать красным полем фигуру (пятиугольник). В случае с четырехугольником прямоугольным все получается

Comment: а в каком месте кода и какими функциями opengl вы делаете отсечение?

Comment: В это участвуют функции  getInterSect(Point s,Point p,int edge) и getInterSect(Point s,Point p,int edge)

Comment: Эти функции не используют OpenGL. У вас GL только рисует.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что сам расчет координат происходит именно там.

Comment: Чтобы остекать с помощью OpenGL, расположите ваши фигуры с разными значениями Z в пространстве - и GL все  сделает сам. От вас, насколько я понимаю, хотят именно этого.

Comment: От меня хотят визуализации отсечения методом Ходжмена-Сазерленда для многоугольника с пятью вершинами. Алгоритм написан, но отрабатывает несколько некорректно (в первом случае на скриншоте)